# Custom date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

**EXPLAINATION**

There are 2 work shifts, day shift = from `07:00:00` to `19:00:00` and night shift = from `19:00:00` to `07:00:00`

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Name    Date        Time        WorkShift
John    2015-09-14  19:14:24    N
John    2015-09-14  23:43:27    N
John    2015-09-15  03:21:36    N
John    2015-09-15  11:29:48    D
```

---

**DESIRED RESULT**

For example I have `@dateStart = 2015-09-14` and `@dateEnd = 2015-09-14` variables. I need to select records from `2015-09-14 19:00:00` to `2015-09-15 07:00:00` in following:

```
John    2015-09-14  19:14:24    N
John    2015-09-14  23:43:27    N
John    2015-09-15  03:21:36    N
```

As you see above, here is date `2015-09-15`, but `Time` is `03:21:36` so It should be selected (because time is lower than `07:00:00`, `N` workshift).

---

**PROBLEMS**

My query selecting as expected, but there are 2 problems.

If I pass `@dateStart = 2015-09-15` and `@dateEnd = 2015-09-15` It selecting:

```
John    2015-09-15  03:21:36    N -- this shouldn't be selected again, this should go as 2015-09-14 
John    2015-09-15  11:29:48    D
```

Another problem is that If I have record like this

```
John    2015-09-15  03:21:36    N
```

As you see there is no any records for `John` in `2015-09-14` so It should be selected when I pass variables in following: `@dateStart = 2015-09-15` and `@dateEnd = 2015-09-15`

---

**QUERY**

```
select *
from SampleTable
where /* Some conditions.... and*/
      (convert(date, StartTime) >= @dateStart) and
      (case when (DateCreated between cast(cast(cast(DateCreated as date) as varchar(40)) + ' 19:00:00' as datetime) 
                              and cast(cast(cast(DateCreated as date) as varchar(40)) + ' 23:59:59' as datetime)
                  or
                  DateCreated between cast(cast(cast(DateCreated as date) as varchar(40)) + ' 00:00:00' as datetime) 
                              and cast(cast(cast(DateCreated as date) as varchar(40)) + ' 07:00:00' as datetime)
                  )
                  and Workshift like '%N'
            then dateadd(day,-1,cast(cast(DateCreated as date) as varchar(40))) 
            else DateCreated
        end <= @dateEnd)
```

If something is unclear - ask me and I will try to explain.

Comment: once when i encountered a similar problem in my attendance register program,i had to use the timestamp along with AM/PM and check for the same to resolve the issue.I think it may help you.why dont you check that way.

Comment: Any specific reason for not taking datetime value in a DATE data type and storing it as varchar instead?

Comment: is `DATE` and `TIME` stored as `varchar`? If so, don't do that and this becomes *much* easier

Comment: @Jamiec, no It is DATETIME datatype.

Comment: Why 2 different fields then? Are *both* datetime?

Comment: You can extract the date part and the time part from a single field - either in sql or in SSRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
select  *
from SampleTable
where convert(dateTime,DateCreated) + convert(dateTime,StartTime) 
between DATEADD(HH,7, @dateStart) and DATEADD(HH,24+7, @dateEnd)
or 
(
    convert(dateTime,DateCreated) + convert(dateTime,StartTime) 
    between DATEADD(HH,00, @dateStart) and DATEADD(HH,7, @dateStart) -- Morning records
    and not exists 
        (
        select 1 from SampleTable where 
        convert(dateTime,DateCreated) + convert(dateTime,StartTime)  
        between DATEADD(HH,7-24, @dateStart) and DATEADD(HH,0, @dateStart)
        ) -- Data from previous day
)
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but seems like wrong. It returning the same result for 14 day and the same result for 15 day (as in example)

Comment: Got it. For every day you need only day shift and night... And you need to select rows for morning records if there is no data from previous day. Updated solution

Comment: Thank you, looks like working after some corrections.

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding hours to the start and end times?

```
where datetime >= dateadd(hour, 19, @datestart) and
      datetime < dateadd(hour, 7, @dateend)
```

If you are storing "date" and "time" in separate columns (which is not generally recommended), you can add them after converting to `datetime`:

```
where cast(date as datetime) + cast(time as datetime) >= dateadd(hour, 19, @datestart) and
      cast(date as datetime) + cast(time as datetime) < dateadd(hour, 7, @dateend)
```